# Jupyter Notebook freezes when creating or opening a notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using Jupyter Notebook in conda environment on a remote server, installed by: `conda install -c anaconda jupyter`. My Jupyter Notebook version is `jupyter-notebook --version` 6.5.4. It's worked in the past and suddenly stopped working.

The problem: I can start Jupyter Notebook, browse directories on the browser or start a terminal but when I create a new notebook or open an existing notebook, a new blank tab pops up and Jupyter Notebook freezes. `ctrl+c` doesn't work for stopping the freezed Jupyter server and I have to `skill -9 {pid}`.

Output of `jupyter-notebook . --debug`:

```
[D 12:47:09.453 NotebookApp] Searching ['{working_dir}DCT/tmp', '{my_user}/.jupyter', '{my_user}/.local/etc/jupyter', '{my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/etc/jupyter', '/usr/local/etc/jupyter', '/etc/jupyter'] for config files
[D 12:47:09.454 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in /etc/jupyter
[D 12:47:09.454 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in /usr/local/etc/jupyter
[D 12:47:09.454 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/etc/jupyter
[D 12:47:09.455 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in {my_user}/.local/etc/jupyter
[D 12:47:09.455 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in {my_user}/.jupyter
[D 12:47:09.455 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in {working_dir}DCT/tmp
[D 12:47:09.456 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in /etc/jupyter
[D 12:47:09.456 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in /usr/local/etc/jupyter
[D 12:47:09.456 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/etc/jupyter
[D 12:47:09.456 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in {my_user}/.local/etc/jupyter
[D 12:47:09.456 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in {my_user}/.jupyter
[D 12:47:09.457 NotebookApp] Loaded config file: {my_user}/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
[D 12:47:09.458 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in {working_dir}DCT/tmp
[D 12:47:09.458 NotebookApp] Raising open file limit: soft 1024->4096; hard 1048576->1048576
[D 12:47:09.501 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_notebook_config: 
        /etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
[D 12:47:09.501 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_notebook_config: 
        /usr/local/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
[D 12:47:09.502 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_notebook_config: 
        {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.d/jupyterlab.json
        {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
[D 12:47:09.503 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_notebook_config: 
        {my_user}/.local/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
[D 12:47:09.503 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of jupyter_notebook_config: 
        {my_user}/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
{my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/paths.py:67: UserWarning: IPython parent '{my_user}' is not a writable location, using a temp directory.
  " using a temp directory.".format(parent))

  _   _          _      _
 | | | |_ __  __| |__ _| |_ ___
 | |_| | '_ \/ _` / _` |  _/ -_)
  \___/| .__/\__,_\__,_|\__\___|
       |_|
                       
Read the migration plan to Notebook 7 to learn about the new features and the actions to take if you are using extensions.

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrate_to_notebook7.html

Please note that updating to Notebook 7 might break some of your extensions.

[W 12:47:11.348 NotebookApp] Loading JupyterLab as a classic notebook (v6) extension.
[W 2023-07-28 12:47:11.355 LabApp] 'port' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2023-07-28 12:47:11.355 LabApp] 'port' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2023-07-28 12:47:11.355 LabApp] 'port' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[I 2023-07-28 12:47:11.363 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2023-07-28 12:47:11.363 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/share/jupyter/lab
[I 12:47:11.368 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: {working_dir}DCT/tmp
[I 12:47:11.368 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.5.4 is running at:
[I 12:47:11.368 NotebookApp] http://localhost:9012/?token=c66993a8d7e7000d0579d4fac88dc40de8f00e1c13a8dc84
[I 12:47:11.369 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:9012/?token=c66993a8d7e7000d0579d4fac88dc40de8f00e1c13a8dc84
[I 12:47:11.369 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 12:47:11.376 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 12:47:11.376 NotebookApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file://{my_user}/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-21834-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:9012/?token=c66993a8d7e7000d0579d4fac88dc40de8f00e1c13a8dc84
     or http://127.0.0.1:9012/?token=c66993a8d7e7000d0579d4fac88dc40de8f00e1c13a8dc84
[I 12:47:20.450 NotebookApp] 302 GET /?token=c66993a8d7e7000d0579d4fac88dc40de8f00e1c13a8dc84 (::1) 1.260000ms
[D 12:47:20.485 NotebookApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 12:47:20.490 NotebookApp] Using contents: services/contents
[D 12:47:20.544 NotebookApp] Path base/images/favicon.ico served from {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbclassic/static/base/images/favicon.ico
[D 12:47:20.548 NotebookApp] Path components/jquery-ui/dist/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css served from {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbclassic/static/components/jquery-ui/dist/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css
[D 12:47:20.550 NotebookApp] Path components/jquery-typeahead/dist/jquery.typeahead.min.css served from {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbclassic/static/components/jquery-typeahead/dist/jquery.typeahead.min.css
[D 12:47:20.551 NotebookApp] Path style/style.min.css served from {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbclassic/static/style/style.min.css
[D 12:47:20.553 NotebookApp] Path components/es6-promise/promise.min.js served from {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbclassic/static/components/es6-promise/promise.min.js
[D 12:47:20.555 NotebookApp] Path components/react/react.production.min.js served from {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbclassic/static/components/react/react.production.min.js
[D 12:47:20.556 NotebookApp] Path components/react/react-dom.production.min.js served from {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbclassic/static/components/react/react-dom.production.min.js
[D 12:47:20.557 NotebookApp] Path components/create-react-class/index.js served from {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbclassic/static/components/create-react-class/index.js
[D 12:47:20.559 NotebookApp] Path components/requirejs/require.js served from {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbclassic/static/components/requirejs/require.js
[D 12:47:20.560 NotebookApp] Path base/images/logo.png served from {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbclassic/static/base/images/logo.png
[D 12:47:20.563 NotebookApp] Path tree/js/main.min.js served from {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbclassic/static/tree/js/main.min.js
[D 12:47:20.569 NotebookApp] 200 GET /tree?token=c66993a8d7e7000d0579d4fac88dc40de8f00e1c13a8dc84 (::1) 84.470000ms
[D 12:47:20.672 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/dist/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css?v=32f9dcde0cd9843f2b66d34c1c9928b59a5d7ef007ba7a6a6a790b3e78f7857a698444d7a716dfaf8fa834c3b3175efd258bbc07cfc4aabb86769b07e5f358c3 (::1) 2.660000ms
[D 12:47:20.691 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/components/jquery-typeahead/dist/jquery.typeahead.min.css?v=5edf53bf6bb9c3b1ddafd8594825a7e2ed621f19423e569c985162742f63911c09eba2c529f8fb47aebf27fafdfe287d563347f58c1126b278189a18871b6a9a (::1) 1.700000ms
[D 12:47:20.733 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/style/style.min.css?v=e1ab1c38b672063a6541baf468c83345cd0f509729783ec9b7ccb64073004f5f056110c82c28aefbf3dbf32e0e040f05b8f0420bc411b669ed3d4f07511812ca (::1) 2.440000ms
[D 12:47:20.912 NotebookApp] Path custom.css served from {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbclassic/static/custom/custom.css
[D 12:47:20.914 NotebookApp] 200 GET /custom/custom.css (::1) 3.610000ms
[D 12:47:20.963 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/components/react/react-dom.production.min.js?v=6fc58c1c4736868ff84f57bd8b85f2bdb985993a9392718f3b4af4bfa10fb4efba2b4ddd68644bd2a8daf0619a3844944c9c43f8528364a1aa6fc01ec1b8ae84 (::1) 4.680000ms
[D 12:47:20.964 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/components/create-react-class/index.js?v=894ad57246e682b4cfbe7cd5e408dcd6b38d06af4de4f3425991e2676fdc2ef1732cbd19903104198878ae77de12a1996de3e7da3a467fb226bdda8f4618faec (::1) 5.270000ms
[D 12:47:20.966 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/components/es6-promise/promise.min.js?v=bea335d74136a63ae1b5130f5ac9a50c6256a5f435e6e09fef599491a84d834a8b0f011ca3eaaca3b4ab6a2da2d3e1191567a2f171e60da1d10e5b9d52f84184 (::1) 5.910000ms
[D 12:47:20.967 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/components/react/react.production.min.js?v=9a0aaf84a316c8bedd6c2ff7d5b5e0a13f8f84ec02442346cba0b842c6c81a6bf6176e64f3675c2ebf357cb5bb048e0b527bd39377c95681d22468da3d5de735 (::1) 6.520000ms
[D 12:47:21.391 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/components/requirejs/require.js?v=d37b48bb2137faa0ab98157e240c084dd5b1b5e74911723aa1d1f04c928c2a03dedf922d049e4815f7e5a369faa2e6b6a1000aae958b7953b5cc60411154f593 (::1) 2.100000ms
[D 12:47:21.669 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/tree/js/main.min.js?v=c577478f1048baae824346f06e346385961e85050981772b336b8d992e46e99f3d67a88d84226bc482453cb76d33ace682623dd1a5595ad3ce44236f05d4a8e1 (::1) 4.660000ms
[D 12:47:21.844 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/base/images/logo.png?v=a2a176ee3cee251ffddf5fa21fe8e43727a9e5f87a06f9c91ad7b776d9e9d3d5e0159c16cc188a3965e00375fb4bc336c16067c688f5040c0c2d4bfdb852a9e4 (::1) 1.870000ms
[D 12:47:29.520 NotebookApp] Path services/contents.js served from {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbclassic/static/services/contents.js
[D 12:47:29.521 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/services/contents.js?v=20230728124709 (::1) 3.630000ms
[D 12:47:29.524 NotebookApp] Path custom-preload.js served from {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbclassic/static/custom/custom-preload.js
[D 12:47:29.525 NotebookApp] 200 GET /custom/custom-preload.js?v=20230728124709 (::1) 2.980000ms
[D 12:47:29.943 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of common: 
        /etc/jupyter/nbconfig/common.json
[D 12:47:29.943 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of common: 
        /usr/local/etc/jupyter/nbconfig/common.json
[D 12:47:29.944 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of common: 
        {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/etc/jupyter/nbconfig/common.json
[D 12:47:29.945 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of common: 
        {my_user}/.local/etc/jupyter/nbconfig/common.json
[D 12:47:29.946 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of common: 
        {my_user}/.jupyter/nbconfig/common.json
[D 12:47:29.946 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/config/common?_=1690519649387 (::1) 8.740000ms
[D 12:47:29.949 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?_=1690519649389 (::1) 10.020000ms
[D 12:47:29.949 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/terminals?_=1690519649390 (::1) 9.630000ms
[D 12:47:29.950 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of tree: 
        /etc/jupyter/nbconfig/tree.json
[D 12:47:29.950 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of tree: 
        /usr/local/etc/jupyter/nbconfig/tree.json
[D 12:47:29.950 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of tree: 
        {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/etc/jupyter/nbconfig/tree.json
[D 12:47:29.950 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of tree: 
        {my_user}/.local/etc/jupyter/nbconfig/tree.json
[D 12:47:29.951 NotebookApp] Paths used for configuration of tree: 
        {my_user}/.jupyter/nbconfig/tree.json
[D 12:47:29.951 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/config/tree?_=1690519649386 (::1) 10.580000ms
{my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/paths.py:67: UserWarning: IPython parent '{my_user}' is not a writable location, using a temp directory.
  " using a temp directory.".format(parent))
[D 12:47:29.955 NotebookApp] Found kernel mm in {my_user}/.local/share/jupyter/kernels
[D 12:47:29.955 NotebookApp] Found kernel python3 in {my_user}/.local/share/jupyter/kernels
[D 12:47:30.614 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/kernelspecs (::1) 672.370000ms
[D 12:47:30.615 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/terminals?_=1690519649388 (::1) 1.020000ms
[D 12:47:30.620 NotebookApp] Path components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2 served from {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbclassic/static/components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2
[D 12:47:30.622 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 (::1) 5.000000ms
[D 12:47:30.625 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/contents?type=directory&_=1690519649391 (::1) 7.550000ms
[D 12:47:30.626 NotebookApp] Path custom.js served from {my_user}/miniconda3/envs/mm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbclassic/static/custom/custom.js
[D 12:47:30.627 NotebookApp] 200 GET /custom/custom.js?v=20230728124709 (::1) 8.570000ms
[D 12:47:30.903 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/base/images/favicon.ico?v=50afa725b5de8b00030139d09b38620224d4e7dba47c07ef0e86d4643f30c9bfe6bb7e1a4a1c561aa32834480909a4b6fe7cd1e17f7159330b6b5914bf45a880 (::1) 1.970000ms
[D 12:48:29.619 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?_=1690519649392 (::1) 1.760000ms
[D 12:48:29.628 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/terminals?_=1690519649393 (::1) 1.110000ms
[D 12:48:29.677 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/contents?type=directory&_=1690519649394 (::1) 4.150000ms
[I 12:48:55.174 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in 
[D 12:48:55.234 NotebookApp] Saving {working_dir}DCT/tmp/Untitled1.ipynb
```

The process freezes after that and Jupyter Notebook becomes unresponsive in the browser. `ctrl+c` is not working and I have to `skill -9 {pid}`.

Things that I tried but are not working:

- changing the browser (Safari, Chrome, Firefox) and local host machine (Ubuntu, Mac) with the same result,
- creating a fresh conda environment and installing Jupyter Notebook only, with the same result,
- tried Jupyter Lab that also freezes after `Creating new notebook in`,
- tried using it in vs code as well as in terminal with ssh & ssh tunneling.

As for the remote server I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver), as I'm not the administrator I'm not aware of any recent changes.